# Twilio MessageResource.Read dates inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: c#, twilio

In the 4.x API, the MessageListRequest interface had a comparison type, ex DateSentComparison = ComparisonType.GreaterThanOrEqualTo. The 5.0 API, MessageResource.Read has dateSentAfter is this inclusive or exclusive?

The documentation doesn't mention this:
https://twilio.github.io/twilio-csharp/5.0.0/class_twilio_1_1_rest_1_1_api_1_1_v2010_1_1_account_1_1_read_message_options.html#aae0de4a5d26814fc646b96b577171d23

```
// Twilio 4.x
var options = new MessageListRequest();
options.DateSent = startTime;
options.DateSentComparison = ComparisonType.GreaterThanOrEqualTo;

// Twilio 5.0
var messages = MessageResource.Read(dateSentAfter: startTime);   // inclusive or exclusive?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

`dateSetAfter` here refers to using `>=` in the [list filter for the messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list-get-filters). It is an inclusive filter. It is the same as the old `GreaterThanOrEqualTo` that you had in the v4 API because the API it refers to hasn't changed.